# How to find which user made the last modification of a table row

Tags: database, oracle

let's say schema `user1` has a table called `user1_table` and user2 has insert/update/delete grants on `user1_table`

I know how to find the last modification date/time as follows

```
SELECT scn_to_timestamp(ORA_ROWSCN)
  FROM user1_table
 WHERE id = 1;
```

Is there a way to find out which user (user1 or user2?) last modified that particular row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know who made the modifications, you need to enable audit. It requires a setup and you have options ( DB , OS )
To allow auditing on the server you must:

- Set `audit_trail = true`
- Run the `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/cataudit.sql script while connected as SYS`.

A simple example would be

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 number , c2 number )
  2  ;

Table created.

SQL> audit insert,update,delete on t by access ;

Audit succeeded.
```

You can also create a trigger to store in a table who made the modification by applying the `SYS_CONTEXT` properties

The example below is a basic one, you can expand the properties of the trigger to control updates and deletes as well.

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 number, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> create table t_audit ( who varchar2(40) , c1 number, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL>
create or replace trigger trg_aud_t after update on t
for each row
declare
v_user varchar2(40);
begin
  select sys_context('userenv','session_user') into v_user from dual;
  insert into t_audit values ( v_user , :new.c1 , :new.c2 );
end;
/SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9

Trigger created.

SQL> update t set c1=2 , c2=2 where c1=1  ;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t_audit ;

WHO                                              C1         C2
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
SYS                                               2          2
```

Comment: Thank you, so I guess without explicitly enabling audit I cannot do it in a similar way as with ORA_ROWSCN

Comment: indeed. You could create a trigger and a custom audit table to tracking all changes. If you only need this for one table, perhaps you could work it out with a trigger and an audit table. If you need this for more than one table, then it is better to do it with audit.